# How to share JSON test files between Android and iOS projects

Tags: android, ios, xcode, gradle, github

We have Android and iOS apps which both have their own native unit tests. We are implementing a new API in both apps and would like to share JSON test files between the two projects rather than duplicate them. This will hopefully ensure the apps don't get out of sync with each other and the backend.

The requirement is to have the JSON in a private GitHub repo that both Android (Gradle) and iOS (Carthage/Xcode) can pull in to use in the tests.

I know both Gradle and Carthage are capable of pulling in git repos, but I'm unsure what structure would be required in the JSON repo.

Gradle appears to require the repo to be buildable by Gradle which, in this case, is obviously not required.

Is it feasible to have a single structure in the JSON repo that both projects can reference?

Assuming it is, what is the best structure/layout?

Comment: How about using git submodules? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: At least for Android Studio, you can create a resources folder at `<project_root>/src/test/resources`.  Perhaps that is where you could put your other repo.

Comment: Git submodules would do the job I think, but we would really prefer not to introduce another mechanism (beyond Gradle/Carthage) if we can help it.